# Creating a weighted rating model/script for vector data

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, field-calculator, attribute-table, relationship-class

I'm using ArcMap and trying to create a model or script that can rate routes based on a weighted calculation of attributes. Right now the individual attributes don't have rating values which I could weight and calculate to a total rating value.

I have a feature that has several attributes. Each attribute has a set of domains that define possible values in each field.

I also have a separate table that has data and is related to each feature through a relationship class (route obstructions). The values in this table area also defined from a set of domains.

What I would like to do is using model builder (which I prefer) or a script,
calculate a numeric value into a new field to form a ***weighted, calculated value***, based on the attributes of the feature.

[image: Example of attribute table of feature]

[image: Example of table related to feature through relationship class]

All these fields have different domains, and essentially what I want is to assign each option from the domains a specific value so that a new field can be calculated based on these values.

The feature also has a related table, and I would like to use the values in the fields of this table in the calculation as well.

Comment: I'm having trouble following the question and figuring how why the domains are relevant and how the related table fits in. Can you give a more specific example, perhaps an example record or two?

Comment: I updated the question with a screenshot of the attribute table of the feature as well as its related table. Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, that does help quite a bit. It looks like you're trying to give pedestrian routes a rating based on several different criteria. I'm not sure how your domains are set up, and whether they already classify/rank the different criteria (ie, numeric coded values, etc.). Somehow you need a rating value based on the criteria value. Whether that is added fields, a new table to query against, or performed in script. I don't think it can be done as part of the same domain, as that would mean each value in the domain actually has two values.

Comment: Personally, I would look at adding rating fields to match all the criteria fields. Then you can focus on a rating formula to calc each one, and a final weighting formula that uses all the rating fields. I don't know enough about scripting to wrap that all into one thing, but often the suggestion for something like this is to break the problem down and tackle it one step at a time, then combine in the end. As it stands this question *might* be too broad for GIS.SE. The related table will be a special problem since it could have a many-to-one relationship to the route table.

Comment: I was thinking to maybe export the attribute table to excel to some IF/THEN statements there, because I'm not totally sure how to do it in ArcGIS.

Comment: If you add ratings fields, you'd mostly be using the field calculator in the attribute table and it's just a question of coming up with the right calculation. You could sort on a field (say gradient), select all records you want to give a particular rating (0-2%), and field calc the value into the new rating field (1). Then select the next range and so on (2.1%-5%, 2, etc.). Those calculations could be combined to do all records at once with if statements (messy) or a case statement (cleaner). There are questions here describing both, and it's probably not much different than Excel.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.